# Single Word for people financially tied to a Loan

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you have a student loan. It's possible that the borrower, cosigner, and student are three different people (Perhaps mom is the borrower, grandma is the cosigner, and I'm the student). Is there a single word that collectively defines our relationship to a loan?

I know that all three parties would be considered authorized parties on the loan, but "authorized parties" is two words, and I'm looking for one.

I know that all individuals are people, but while both "individuals" and "people" are one word, they do not imply an association to a loan (In the context that I'm going for, there are people/parties that aren't associated to loans from a borrower/cosigner/student perspective [i.e. the university/bank that granted the loan, the customer service representative that bugs you about paying back your loan, etc]).

I've also considered using "borrower" for this, but then when being descriptive, you have to say "borrower-borrower" to refer to the actual borrower (meaning not the cosigner or student).

Additional types of people could include a payor, being someone who is authorized to make payments on a loan, but is not necessarily financially responsible for the loan (and is also not already the borrower, cosigner, or student).

With all of these relations in mind, it's difficult to find a word that describes all of these individuals, as not everyone is financially responsible for the loan (i.e payor and student [if not the borrower/cosigner]), and not everyone receives disbursements on the loan (i.e. cosigner and payor), and not everyone makes payments on the loan (i.e. cosigner and student [if not the borrower]).

Right now, the shortest description I can think of is "authorized users", but I'm still not a fan of how long that is.

Comment: Client.  One word, your rule.  They're all clients.

Comment: Unfortunately the term "client" is analogous to "lender" in the scope that I'm wanting to use it in. Otherwise, good idea.

Comment: They're all parties to the loan.  Of course, there are parties on the lending side, too--or at least one.

Answer (score 2):

All parties in the OP are **encumbered** by this loan in one way or another.

**Encumber:** "1. Weigh down, burden...2. to impede or hamper the function or activity of [*the parties to the loan* - **emphasis added** ]; to burden with a lagal claim (such as a mortgage) encumber an estate." (M-W)

Comment: I would add 'parties': *encumbered parties*

Comment: Encumbered alone doesn't imply that they're people, but rather describes them. As Unrelated said, you'd have to add 'parties', making your answer two words. Good thinking though.

Comment: @Boom I'm hesitant to add a word not wanting to encumber myself...

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I'd properly borrow a term from business and project development/management and possible use "**stakeholder**"

> a person or group that has an investment, share, or interest in
>   something, as a business or industry.
>   http://www.dictionary.com

All people mentioned have an interest in the loan and its process and financial progress, so the term could be applicable, also as all of them even have an economical interest as well. It might be too 'cumbersome' for your usage though.

Comment: It's certainly an interesting idea. While I'd normally think of the lender/university to be the stakeholder, that's not a word we're currently using for them, so it might work well for this instead.